# Getting an "Invalid Version: 0.0.1alpha1" error when trying to install eslint

Tags: node.js, npm, eslint

Trying to install eslint in recent versions of node (v5.5.0 or 5.9.0).

Running npm install --save-dev eslint on node v5.9.0 (npm v3.7.3) gives me an error:

```
Invalid Version: 0.0.1alpha1
```

An ancient version of node (node v0.10.43, npm v1.4.29) installs it without a problem.

Do you know what the problem might be and how to fix it?

**UPDATE:** Just made sure that eslint loads on node v4.4.1 that is recommended on the Node site as an LTS release. The npm version is 2.14.20.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error occurred because one of the dependencies of `eslint` must have used an invalid `semver` spec. The version should have been `0.0.1-alpha1` for it to be valid.

I've installed `eslint` successfully using Node `5.9.0` and npm `3.7.3` so the module's version must have been updated.

Comment: Curious. I wonder whether this module update happened within the last 20 hours. Will try to reinstall later today. Thank you for the explanation.